# access to original dict after a KeyError

Tags: python, dictionary, exception, stack-trace

If I catch an KeyError exception in python, I can easily get the key that was failed.  Is there a way to access the keys that are in the dictionary?
I know the exception itself doesn't have the information, but is there a way to find it from the stack trace?

Comment: Whitout code it's hard to say, but if you know in which dictionnary the exception is trown then you can simply acces it's keys with `a.keys()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the exception doesn't retain a reference to the dictionary that threw the exception. As such, you cannot enumerate the keys that do exist from just the exception.

Comment: One might be able to reach into the traceback object and grab local variables out of it...  More useful in pdb than in actual code, though.

Comment: @Kevin: and that presumes that the dictionary is actually bound to a variable. That's not a given either. And you still won't know *which dictionary*. There could be 0 or more dictionaries associated with the top frame in the traceback, which one threw the exception?